# Any NLP API or Utility for Hadoop?

Tags: hadoop, twitter, nlp

I am working on large scare text based analysis. More precisely I am doing Sentiment analysis on Twitter data for particular products.
I am using Flume to pull Twitter data in HDFS. 
Is there any NLP API or Utility I can apply on these twitts to get correct and meaningful sentiment out of it?

I am looking for NLP API or utility that i can use in Hadoop system.

Answer (score 3):

Two possible solutions are:

- Integrating [nltk](http://www.nltk.org/) with Hadoop. Some resources: http://strataconf.com/stratany2013/public/schedule/detail/30806, http://www.datacommunitydc.org/blog/2013/05/nltk-hadoop, https://danrosanova.files.wordpress.com/2014/04/practical-natural-language-processing-with-hadoop.pdf
- Using Apache Mahout, http://www.slideshare.net/Hadoop_Summit/stella-june27-1150amroom210av2

Comment: Thanks snkherv for your quick revert. let me check these options. Thanks again